# Trying to learn Ab Scale on Piano, and can't make sense of the fingers

Tags: piano, scales, fingering

I am trying to learn Ab Scale, and fingers are tripping me up. I only know C Major till now and a beginner, so please help.

For right hand : Its suppose to be 2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 but I am starting Ab on 2 and ending at 3, isn't this weird. Wouldn't it be better to start Ab on 3 so I can end on 3 as well (similar to C Major where I use 1 if I want to switch up octaves).

The left hand is following that principle starting and ending Ab at 3, so why is the 4th finger never used in right hand and when I move up octaves, wouldn't I end up using 3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3. So why not start the scale at 3 as well, what part am I getting wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm: the only scale you know is `C` major, and the next scale you are learning is `Ab` major?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Supposed to be' according to who?

23123123 might be considered superficially 'easier' when playing just one octave of the scale.

34123123 keeps the fingering consistent when continuing into a second octave.

The first couple of online resources I found suggest 34123123.  I agree with them. I think you should too.

https://www.pianoscales.org/major.html

http://robertkelleyphd.com/home/teaching/keyboard/keyboard-scale-fingering-chart/

Comment: According to a couple of youtube videos and reddit post I found. I was wondering if there were any accidentals commonly used near A# that were easier managed by starting at 2. Would likely start at 3 myself, since it felt more natural and comfortable.

Comment: In isolation, Ab, Bb, C is probably 'easier' 231.   But in the context of a continuing Ab major scale, 321 is necessary.  You don't HAVE to play every fragment as if it was part of a scale though.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're only playing one octave. If you continue for another octave you'll end up playing the Ab with RH3 and Bb with RH4. You could start the scale that way if you like, but 2 3 make the thumb movement easier. Do whatever works for you.

Comment: Any specific accidentals that are easier managed by starting at 2, or is all about personal comfort?

Comment: @AnonyMous It's all about comfort. Start with 2 for comfort, or with 3 to make the fingering consistent across octaves.